# What is wrong with cmake under mingw

Tags: windows, cmake, mingw

```
mkdir build
cd build
cmake -G "MinGW Makefiles" ..
```

```
CMake Error at I:/msys64/mingw32/share/cmake-3.13/Modules/CMakeMinGWFindMake.cmake:12 (message):
  sh.exe was found in your PATH, here:

  I:/msys64/usr/bin/sh.exe

  For MinGW make to work correctly sh.exe must NOT be in your path.

  Run cmake from a shell that does not have sh.exe in your PATH.

  If you want to use a UNIX shell, then use MSYS Makefiles.

Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:16 (PROJECT)


CMake Error: CMAKE_C_COMPILER not set, after EnableLanguage
CMake Error: CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER not set, after EnableLanguage
-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

but it would appear the the offending `sh.exe` is part of msys??

### OK so try the msys shell... `i:\msys64\mingw32`

```
rm -rf build
mkdir build
cd build
cmake -G "MinGW Makefiles" ..
```

```
CMake Error at I:/msys64/mingw32/share/cmake-3.13/Modules/CMakeMinGWFindMake.cmake:12 (message):
  sh.exe was found in your PATH, here:

  I:/msys64/usr/bin/sh.exe

  For MinGW make to work correctly sh.exe must NOT be in your path.

  Run cmake from a shell that does not have sh.exe in your PATH.

  If you want to use a UNIX shell, then use MSYS Makefiles.

Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:16 (PROJECT)


CMake Error: CMake was unable to find a build program corresponding to "MinGW Makefiles".  CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM is not set.  You probably need to select a different build tool.
CMake Error: CMake was unable to find a build program corresponding to "MinGW Makefiles".  CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM is not set.  You probably need to select a different build tool.
CMake Error: CMAKE_C_COMPILER not set, after EnableLanguage
CMake Error: CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER not set, after EnableLanguage
-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

same thing.

should `sh.exe` not be there?

### one last try...

`cmake -G "MinGW Makefiles" -DCMAKE_SH="CMAKE_SH-NOTFOUND" ..`

```
$ cmake -G "MinGW Makefiles" -DCMAKE_SH="CMAKE_SH-NOTFOUND" ..
CMake Error: CMake was unable to find a build program corresponding to "MinGW Makefiles".  CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM is not set.  You probably need to select a different build tool.
CMake Error: CMake was unable to find a build program corresponding to "MinGW Makefiles".  CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM is not set.  You probably need to select a different build tool.
CMake Error: CMAKE_C_COMPILER not set, after EnableLanguage
CMake Error: CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER not set, after EnableLanguage
-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

So it would seem there's a second problem as well?

any help? thanks.

Comment: Like the error message says, if you're running under an MSYS shell, you should use `cmake -G "MSYS Makefiles" ...` **not** `cmake -G "MinGW Makefiles" ...`

Answer (score 1):

First of all, make sure you have `mingw32-make` installed:

```
which mingw32-make
```

if not `/mingw64/bin/mingw32-make` then either the path is not in your `~/.bashrc` or it is not installed. I think you can install it by

```
pacman -S mingw64/mingw-w64-x86_64-make
```

which is also part of `mingw-w64-x86_64-toolchain` that you have probably already installed. then you should be able to run

```
cmake -D CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM:PATH=/mingw64/bin/mingw32-make
```

please give it a try and let me know if this works for you.